# How can I add name to existing value pair in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table

Hello this is my sample json:

```
 {
  "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z": 1,
  "2016-02-01T00:00:00Z": 2,
  "2016-03-01T00:00:00Z": 3
}
```

Now I want something like

```
[
  {"Month":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z", "Number": 1},
  {"Month":"2016-02-01T00:00:00Z", "Number": 2},
  {"Month":"2016-03-01T00:00:00Z", "Number": 3}
]
```

How can I do this using JS/Jquery? I wanted to change it to the above mentioned format because I need to put them in html table and I found out that using the second format makes my job easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this in the following way

```js
let obj = {
  "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z": 1,
  "2016-02-01T00:00:00Z": 2,
  "2016-03-01T00:00:00Z": 3
};
let result = [];
for(element in obj){
    result.push({"Month":element, "Number": obj[element]})
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function to change the format of an array.

```
let jsonArray = {
    "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z": 1,
    "2016-02-01T00:00:00Z": 2,
    "2016-03-01T00:00:00Z": 3
};

var result = $.map(jsonArray, function (item, key) {
    return {
        Month: key,
        Number: item
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the keys with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for mapping the new objects.

```js
var object = { "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z": 1, "2016-02-01T00:00:00Z": 2, "2016-03-01T00:00:00Z": 3 },
    result = Object.keys(object).map(function (k) {
        return { Month: k, Number: object[k] };
    });

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var object1 =  {
      "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z": 1,
      "2016-02-01T00:00:00Z": 2,
      "2016-03-01T00:00:00Z": 3
    };

    var finalArray = [];

    for (var key in object1) {
      if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {   // p.hasOwnProperty this will check for duplicate key
            finalArray.push({
            “Month” : key,
            “Number”:p[key]
        });
      }
    }

console.log(finalArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could include using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) along with  [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as such...

```
let obj = {
  '2016-01-01T00:00:00Z': 1,
  '2016-02-01T00:00:00Z': 2,
  '2016-03-01T00:00:00Z': 3
}

let arr = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    return {'Month': key, 'Number': obj[key]}
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/40btx3rq/)

Answer (score 0):

use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for travelling

```
 a = {
      "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z": 1,
      "2016-02-01T00:00:00Z": 2,
      "2016-03-01T00:00:00Z": 3
    }

var b = []; 
$.each( a, function( key, value ) {
   b.push({mounth: key ,number: value });
});
```

Output will be:

```
0:{mounth: "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z", number: 1}
1:{mounth: "2016-02-01T00:00:00Z", number: 2}
2:{mounth: "2016-03-01T00:00:00Z", number: 3}
```